# Android Javascript Wrapper can't call any function in outer class?

Tags: java, android

```
public class main extends Activity {
/*
    The function videoViewURL(url) works anywhere else
    in my program but here!!

    It needs to be called from one of these places.
    I think it has to do with class hiearchy.
    Also I believe passing the function setUrl(url) another parameter might work.
    The other parameter being a Function

    So what I'm asking is this.  Does anyone know how to pass   


    setUrl(url, function videoViewURL(url)){
        videoViewURL(this.url);
    }



*/
    public void videoViewURL(String url){
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
    mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);
    Uri video = Uri.parse(url);
    videoView.setVisibility(VideoView.VISIBLE);
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.start();          
       // mc.show();
    }


    public class jsVideo{    // Option1
        public void setUrl(String url){
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     This works and returning valid url!
        videoViewURL(url);  // This doesn't
    }
}

}


class jsVideo{      // Option2
    public void setUrl(String url){
    Context mContext;
    // I've even tryed  main m;
        jsVideo(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
            // m = main;  but this still doesn't work
        }

    //Toast.makeText(mContext;, url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     This works and returning valid url!
    videoViewURL(url);  // This doesn't
}
```

My VideoView works that's not the problem, it just won't let me call it from these two spots.  If I could attach the project I would, but I stripped this down to as compact as I could get it.  Thank you.

Comment: Where adding javascript interface  in webview  for calling `jsVideo` method from javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

This is before onCreate()

```
    final Handler myHandler = new Handler();
```

This is where it is in the example.

```
    public class jsVideo{  // <stupid Class Object Wrapper
        public void setUrl(String url){
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           final String msgURL = url;
           myHandler.post(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                    videoViewURL(msgURL);
            }
        });
       }
     }
```